# How to determine whether DNS is being redirected or not?

Tags: networking, router, dns, redirection, isp

I am trying to use a DNS server benchmarking utility ([namebench](https://code.google.com/archive/p/namebench/)) to optimize my connection.  I have used this same utility before, and it didn't give me any issues previously; I realized that I had run a clean OS install a little while ago so my local settings were wiped.

I changed my router DNS settings from previous (dated) results to obtain from ISP, flushed DNS cache, then proceeded to run namebench but was met with an error message:

[image]

Since I know it's not the router, I reached out to my ISP (Charter Spectrum) and asked their technical support, but they advised they do not intercept or redirect DNS requests.

I'm not that knowledgeable when it comes to networking issues, so I figured I should come and ask here what the most likely cause is and how to resolve it?  I did confirm at least one other end-user submitted this behavior on the issue-tracking page, but the dev team has not accepted / addressed the issue yet. 
 Thank you!

EDIT: In response to the new information provided in the below answer, I'm updating my post to include more information in hopes that it will clarify and help narrow things down.

- While I do have CyberGhost VPN installed, I don't have it running on startup and only turn it on once in a while.  It definitely wasn't running during the benchmarking to my knowledge (unless there's some background process or service running under an obfuscated name).
- I do not have any parental control software installed, and WinDefender is the only active anti-malware running (not by *my* choice); I have Malwarebytes + Spybot installed, but only for manual scans for the former and browser inoculation for the latter; again, neither run on startup.
- I *do* use the AdBLockPlus browser extension (running on Vivaldi and Chrome); I've also modified my host file to include [these](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/alternates/fakenews-gambling-social/hosts).
- I have router Guest Wifi disabled; NAT is set to Open.
- My hardware:

  - Arris SURFboard (SB6190) (Non-ISP)
  - Netgear X4S R7800 (Non-ISP)
  - Win 10 Pro x64
  - Asus ROG Hero X Maximus (Wifi AC)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to determine whether DNS is being redirected or not?

One method is to send a query whose response depends on the server. The trick is to check 5-6 different servers, and expect to receive 5-6 different responses. Now that doesn't guarantee that DNS interception is not happening... but if you keep getting the same response every time (or no response at all), that's definitely an indication that DNS interception *is* in fact happening.

Many (but not all) DNS servers respond to the following queries with their own hostname or some other partially unique label:

- hostname.bind/CH/TXT
- id.server/CH/TXT

For example, all of `[a-m].root-servers.net` (the DNS root zone servers) will respond to this check. (Note that they're anycast, so depending on your location you will get a different response than my example shows; that's normal.)

This is how you make such queries on Windows:

```
C:\>nslookup -class=CHAOS -q=TXT hostname.bind j.root-servers.net
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.58.128.30

Non-authoritative answer:
hostname.bind   text =

        "rootns-wie2"
```

Level3 public DNS servers (4.2.2.[1-5]) also respond to both queries (although neither CloudFlare nor Google public DNS do):

- `nslookup -class=CHAOS -q=TXT hostname.bind 4.2.2.2`

---

A second method: Some DNS servers also offer a different kind of check – they have a query which always responds with *your own* IP address. If you run this query directly against that server, and it shows an IP address different from your router's "WAN" address, that is always a bad sign.

A few known IP address checkers:

- `nslookup whoami.akamai.net. ns1-1.akamaitech.net.`
- `nslookup -q=TXT o-o.myaddr.l.google.com. ns2.google.com.`
- `nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com.`

> what the most likely cause is and how to resolve it?

It could be some VPN software that you have installed on the computer. (This redirection might be part of the "DNS leak prevention" feature.)

It could be some malware or parental control software that you have installed on the computer or the router.

It could be some ad-blocking system that you have. (For example, Pi-hole is often used with DNS redirection, as it works by preventing DNS requests to ad servers.)

It could be the router's "captive portal" feature (a common part of "guest Wi-Fi" or "public Wi-Fi" configuration, used to provide webbrowser-based Wi-Fi login forms).

It could, of course, be the ISP's support people not knowing anything about what the network people are actually doing. For example (I'm talking in general, not about Charter/Spectrum), the ISP might experiment with DNS interception to enforce government-mandated website blocking.

> Since I know it's not the router

You haven't actually shown that it's not the router.

The "DNS servers" setting in routers is usually advisory. It's published via DHCP so that your OS would know what servers to use when a program uses the generic gethostbyname()-type functions, but it is **not usually enforced**. If a program doesn't use these functions – that is, if it builds and sends its own DNS queries over TCP/UDP, like namebench does – then OS or router configuration is simply bypassed.

The error message is talking about a **different** kind of configuration: firewall/NAT rules which actually intercept all outgoing DNS packets and redirect them to a new destination. These could be manually created, or added as part of (e.g.) parental control features, or installed by malware on the router.

(Router behavior is not set in stone; ISPs sometimes push out firmware updates which might add features or change how something works.)